# Deploy Bot to MS Teams using Azure or App Studio?

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm having really annoying problems getting my bot to work in MS Teams. I created it using Bot Framework v4 and deployed it to Azure. I deployed the bot using Direct Line from the "channels" blade and it's working ok. Then in the same blade I deployed it to MS Teams. And that [caused issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57278351/oauth-card-in-ms-teams).

People are telling me that the problem has to do with something about a manifest file and a "valid domains" setting I have to edit. I don't know what those are and I never had to do any of this when I told Azure to deploy it to MS Teams. It seems there's a whole different way to deploy the bot to teams, which is using App studio. I tried that way, and now I see another different issue.

So it doesn't work for me when I deploy with Azure or using App Studio. And I want to research and fix the issues, but first I need to know which method should I try to fix? Which am I supposed to use to deploy to MS Teams? Azure or App Studio?

Note: I'm not asking how to fix these issues. I want to know which method of deployment I am supposed to use. What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Let's get the terminology straight first. You are building a bot. In Teams, a bot is just one of the possible *capabilities* of a Teams app. (The others are tabs, connectors, and messaging extensions.)

The definition of a Teams app is defined at a high level [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/apps/apps-overview).

Creating an app package (which is one of the things App Studio can do) is defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/apps/apps-package) - App Studio can also sideload/upload apps (see below).

Once you've created it, you need to make it available within Teams, first for yourself (and potentially others, if it's allowed in your tenant) via sideloading/uploading, or for your entire organization if you like. That's defined in [Upload an app package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/apps/apps-upload), with in-depth discussion of the tenant app catalog [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/publishing/apps-publish).